# Flutterwave payment API integration with PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, api, integration, flutterwave

How do I update  mysql db  payment status  from pending to success in the flutterwave api please find the code snippet below. the db connection is included from a controller.php file

<php?

if($amountPaid >= $amountToPay)
{

```
                echo 'Payment successful';

                //* Continue to give item to the user
                $res = json_decode($response);
                $array= json_decode($response,true);
               
            $payment_id = $array["data"]["id"];
            $transaction_amount = $array["data"]["amount"];
            $payment_status = $array["status"];
            $tx_ref = $array["data"]["tx_ref"];
            
      
            $query3 = "UPDATE transaction_details SET payment_id=$payment_id , payment_status= 
            $payment_status WHERE tx_ref=$tx_ref";
            

            if ($conn->query($query3) === TRUE) {
              echo "Record updated successfully";
            } else {
              echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
            }
            
            $conn->close();
                
     
                
             
                 header('location: congratulations.php');
             }  else {
                echo 'unusual transaction detected';
            }
          
    }else
    {
        echo 'Can not process payment';
    }
}
```

}
?>

Comment: Please be careful with the way you are interacting with the database. Your code is currently open to [SQL Injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) which should be corrected

Comment: thanks @hppycoder, new to this. can you help with my question ?

Comment: We want to help but you didn't provide enough details. For starters what does `$response` have in it?

Comment: ..but I'm thinking the update query should.. well update based on variable conditions from the success or otherwise of the transaction

Comment: I know it's a JSON object, but what's the content of it? Update your question text with the full JSON content for `$response`

Comment: Ok thanks everyone just figured it out . Had the problem because I sort of mixed up my coding styles using OOP and procedural in same codelines. solved it by using mysqli procedural prepared statement. This helped me to bind the variables to mysql db fields

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks everyone just figured it out . Had the problem because I sort of mixed up my coding styles using OOP and procedural in same codelines. solved it by using mysqli procedural prepared statement. This helped me to bind the variables to mysql db fields